# How to perform button click operation using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to perform click operation for `Buy now` button in flipkart through javascript by executing it in chrome console. Using below code

```
function timeout_trigger() {
  var buynowButton = document.getElementsByClassName("_2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2kuvG8 _7UHT_c")[0];
  console.log(buynowButton)
  buynowButton.click();
}

setTimeout('timeout_trigger()', 2000);
```

I am able to see the button element in console log as i printed using

```
console.log(buynowButton)
```

But, When click method on buynowButton is not working for that flipkart page

```
buynowButton.click();
```

Comment: i need to buy products programmatically to be precise using  java script

Comment: You could use `buynowButton.onclick({target: buynowButton});`

Comment: Please define "_is not working_". What you expect to happen when a click occurs? And what happens instead? What does the click method on `buynowButton` look like?

Comment: I went to Flipkart to check out why is it possible for you to not work. I updated my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159816/how-to-perform-button-click-operation-using-javascript/55160358#55160358)

Answer (score 2):

Flipkart don't use `click()` event for theirs buttons!
It uses Ruby's `onClick` and some sort of complicated system to prevent auto clicking on their site.
They use function called `handleClick`, that they give to button as if it was  named `onClick` but really is called `o()`. And they use special kind of Event to handle it. That's why you cannot use `.click()`, they blocked it by setting `btn.click = ()=>{}`. They also used very complicated system to prevent clicking automatically, so basicly you just have to figure out how to bypass that somehow.

Answer (score 1):

dont call the `timeout_trigger` as a string and pass it as a reference instead.
try :

```
function timeout_trigger() {
  var buynowButton = document.getElementsByClassName("_2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2kuvG8 _7UHT_c")[0];
  console.log(buynowButton)
  buynowButton.click();
}

setTimeout(timeout_trigger, 2000);
```

EDITED

Comment: More like: `setTimeout(timeout_trigger, 2000)` or `setTimeout(()=>timeout_trigger(), 2000)`

Comment: I tried with code suggested, i am able to see the log value , meaning timout_trigger function is invoked but the buynowButton.click() is not adding the product to cart

Comment: @rocky In that case the problem lies elsewhere, the provided code works as it is.

Comment: yes agreed..but it was not working on flipkart website to book flashsale

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log('Clicked');
})

var clickBtn = function() {
  var buynowButton = document.getElementById('btn');
  buynowButton.click();
}

setTimeout(function(){
  clickBtn();
}, 1000)
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Removed jQuery and added back.

Comment: I dont see a jQuery tag

Comment: @DennisLukas Removed jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the function reference in the setTimeout's first parameter.

```
var timeout_trigger = function(){
var buynowButton = document.getElementsByClassName("_2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2kuvG8 _7UHT_c")[0];
console.log(buynowButton)
buynowButton.click();   
}
setTimeout(timeout_trigger, 2000);
```

Comment: Function declared with `function` keyword can work as a variable too. `setTimeout(timeout_trigger, 2000)` would be valid also when he declares it `function timeout_trigger`

Answer (score -3):

Triggering a button in jQuery is easy.

```
$("#id").trigger('click');
```

or simply

```
$("#id").click();
```

Also, don't call your timeout function as a string.

```
setTimeout(timeout_trigger(), 2000);
```

Comment: Why jquery? OP is using native DOM API.